# postgres LOWER( ) works not properly for Turkish characters

Tags: postgresql

Simpyle run the query;

```
select LOWER('I'); //expected: 'ı' actual: 'i'
select LOWER('İ'); //expected 'i' actual 'İ'
```

how to change collation of entire database?

version : "PostgreSQL 10.13"